# BeautifulSoup passing div

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I would like passing this page:

http://animedigitalnetwork.fr/video/naruto-shippuden

I test this:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://animedigitalnetwork.fr/video/naruto-shippuden')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
first_div = soup.find('div',{"class" : "adn-video"})
```

result is not naruto !?

```
<div class="adn-video"> <div class="adn-video_screenshot">
<img src="http://image.animedigitalnetwork.fr/license/claymore/tv/web/eps1_328x184.jpg" alt="Claymore 1" /><span class="adn_video_play-button"></span> </div><div class="adn-video_text"><div class="adn-video_title">
<h4>Claymore</h4><span>Épisode 1</span><div class="adn-rating mobile-hide" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"><meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.6667" /><meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="10" /><div id="adn-rating"><ul class="adn-rating_empty"><li>&#xe002;</li><li>&#xe002;</li><li>&#xe002;</li><li>&#xe002;</li><li>&#xe002;</li></ul><ul class="adn-rating_rating"><li>&#xe002;</li><li>&#xe002;</li><li>&#xe002;</li><li>&#xe002;</li><li>&#xe002;</li></ul></div><p class="adn-rating-message"></p></div></div><div class="adn-video_link">
<a title="Claymore 1" href="/video/claymore/1849-episode-1-la-claymore">Voir la vidéo</a>
</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues here:

- there is an additional asynchronous call involved in forming the list of videos:

  - first you need to extract the `playlist` parameter value from the initial page
  - then, make a post request to get the videos to [this url](http://animedigitalnetwork.fr/index.php?option=com_vodvideo&view=playlist&format=raw')
- you are using an [outdated and not maintained version](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) of `BeautifulSoup` - switch to [`bs4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

  ```
  pip install beautifulsoup4
  ```
- use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of `urllib2`, maintain a [session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) and pass request headers

The complete working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

# initialize session
session = requests.Session()

# getting playlist
response = session.get('http://animedigitalnetwork.fr/video/naruto-shippuden', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
playlist = soup.find('a', {'data-playlist': True})['data-playlist']

# getting list of videos
url = 'http://animedigitalnetwork.fr/index.php?option=com_vodvideo&view=playlist&format=raw'
response = session.post(url, data={
    'playlist': playlist,
    'season': '',
    'order': 'DESC'
}, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
for video in soup.select('div.adn-video'):
    print video.a.get('title')
```

Prints (list of video titles):

```
Naruto Shippuden 391
Naruto Shippuden 390
Naruto Shippuden 389
...
Naruto Shippuden 3
Naruto Shippuden 2
Naruto Shippuden 1
```